# How to stop preg_replace replacing more than once

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string and I want to add a line break after the two first words:

```
$string = 'This is my string I want to but cut.
```

What I have so far is that a line break is added after *every* two words but that’s not what I want …

```
preg_replace( '~((\w+\s){2})~i', '$1' . '<br>', $string );
```

Answer (score 4):

The function [preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject ,$limit = -1, &$count)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) offers the optional argument `$limit` that is set by default to `-1`, which means 'unlimited'.

The spec says the following about `$limit`:

> The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject
>   string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

Thus, add the limit argument to your call of the preg_replace-function, to make it only replace once:

```
preg_replace( '~((\w+\s){2})~i', '$1' . '<br>', $strong, 1);
```

Comment: Perfect – that works fine! Thanks for sharing the information!

Answer (score 1):

Add `^` pattern to your regex to match the beginning of your string:

```
preg_replace( '~^((\w+\s){2})~i', '$1<br>', $strong );
```